# Find supremum in an expression containing trace

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on a problem in which I need to find the supremum of an expression. Namely, the expression below:

$$
 \sup_{w > 0}\Big\{\operatorname{tr}[ \rho \log w] - \log\operatorname{tr}[\sigma w ]\Big\}
$$

where $\rho$ is a density matrix (positive semi-definite Hermitian operator of trace one) and $\sigma$ is a positive semi-definite operator. You can see this expression [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.02615).

The first thing that comes to my mind, is taking the derivative of the expression and setting it to zero to find the answer. However, I do not know how to calculate the derivative of the above expression. I know how to take the derivative of trace in basic cases (i.e. the cases in The Matrix Cookbook) but I need help in this case.

I have also looked at similar expressions where sup was calculated, to solve the above problem, but I did not understand those either. The examples are the following from [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.02383) paper:

$$ 
\sup_{w {\geq} 0}\Big\{\operatorname{tr} \rho \log w - \log\operatorname{tr}\exp(\log w + \log \sigma)\Big\}
$$
and
$$
 \sup_{w \in S(A)}\Big\{\operatorname{tr} H w - D(w\,\|\,\sigma)\Big\}
$$

$S(A)$ is the set of density matrices on $A$, $H$ is a Hermitian operator and $D(w\,\|\,\sigma)$ is the relative entropy.

I would appreciate to know how to calculate the derivative or take the supremum in general or even a resource where I can learn from.

Comment: Is there a reason that you want to compute the supremum exactly? I was under the impression that a lot of these variational forms for quantities were more proof tools than methods for computation.

Comment: I want it for proving something.